# Unable to install Ubuntu MATE 15.10 on Alienware 15; missing drive and confusing boot options

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, windows-10

I'm able to boot into the LiveCD, and I theoretically could install it, but there are some issues.

In both `gparted` in the Ubuntu MATE LiveCD and in Gparted Live, I cannot see my SSD (which has Windows 10 installed on it), but only my HDD (two empty NTFS partitions) and the thumbdrive that the lLiveCD is installed on.

However, when I try to install Ubuntu, the installer complains about an OS previously installed in <kbd>BIOS Compatibility Mode</kbd> and advises against forcing UEFI mode as the other OS may fail to boot. I have not tried to force UEFI mode, but when I click <kbd>Go Back</kbd>, the installation continues.

It only offers me the option to erase Windows and partition manually; if I choose the latter option, I see the same drives as in `gparted`. If I change the firmware to "Legacy Boot" I still can't see my SSD in `gparted`, but I no longer get the complaint about BIOS Compatibility Mode. I then have the options only to erase Windows or partition manually, but I can see the SSD when I choose the latter.

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14109067/) is the output of `lshw`.

*How should I proceed?*

The SSD in question is a Samsung NVMe PM951, connected via PCIe.

I'm wondering if Windows 10 is what's causing the problem.

Update:

I erased Windows 10 and now Ubuntu still fails to detect the SSD in Gparted and lshw. It detects it in the installer and command line Parted in both Legacy and UEFI mode, and I'm able to install it either way.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please use the "Try Ubuntu" mode, go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `sudo lshw`. Then [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the command to http://paste.ubuntu.com and the link of that into your question so we can see what exact hardware you have. Then leave a comment @Fabby.

Comment: Done. See here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14109067/

Comment: For the future, please [edit] your original question to respond to a RFI.  Indeed, the hardware enumeration only sees a `Seagate - ST1000LM044 HN-M` disk.  What is the exact make/model of the SSD?  (use both the BIOS and `msinfo32` under Windows to extract that info).

Comment: Forgive my n00bness, but am I correct in assuming RFI is request for info?

Comment: Yes!!! ***:-)***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalled Windows 10, and while Gparted doesn't see the SSD, I can install Ubuntu to it in either boot mode.